# Force div to expand only vertically

Tags: dynamic, html

I know there are plenty of answers about this, but something I do not get right, as my knowledge level of CSS is below elementary.
I have a `div` which I dynamically populate with `labels` (asp .net in code behind). I would like this div to expand only vertically, having a fixed width (say to 100% of the page). The layout I try to achieve is the one of a paragraph consisting of words represented by the `<asp:Label>` items.

Any help is mostly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

[Expand Divs Vertically](http://www.rmsjr.com/blog/web-design/getting-divs-to-expand-vertically/) has detailed information and possible methods. It might be helpfull.